# Does Amazon RDS Oracle support partition or not?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, database-partitioning

Recently I'm evaluating the feasibility to migrate current application to Amazon RDS Oracle, since the scale of the data becomes larger and larger.

I want to know whether Amazon RDS Oracle could support partition or not. If yes, how to configure it? If no, then if the data scale exceeds the limitation of single instance, how can I scale to multiple instances?

Comment: It's right there in the FAQ: yes. http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

No amazon RDS won't support partitioning.

Both my team and RDS team worked on it and RDS team can't reach performance of 8 Core 16 GB machine, even they are not able to perform.

So my conclusion is if we have partitioning then don't choose RDS.